# Not recognized sencha-touch-all-debug.js in my sencha touch project

Tags: iphone, extjs, sencha-touch, cordova, sencha-touch-2.1

I am creating a Sencha touch app. When I added `sencha-touch-all-debug.js`, then `app.js` is not called. But when I added `sencha-touch-debug.js`, `app.'s`is called. What is problem in my code? please help me

This is my code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../SwatiApp/touch/resources/css/sencha-touch.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
<script charset="utf-8" src="../SwatiApp/touch/sencha-touch-all-debug.js"></script>
<script src="../CordovaLib/javascript/cordova-1.8.1.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

Comment: Show us your app.json, SDK version & Sencha Cmd version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can used `Cordova FrameWork` for sencha-touch implementation.